# Castle Windsor life style depend on forms authentication with cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a user class in my framework and I want to initial the first time when login.

```
   public  class UserClass
{
    public  void Initial(string userId, string userName)
    {

        UserId = useriId;
        UserName = userName;

    }

    public  string UserId { get; private set; }
    public  string UserName { get; private set; }
}
```

I want life  this class depend on

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your `Initial` method is meant to be a constructor for `UserClass` or an init function. You might approach the solution differently depending on that. In either case, there's three ways I'd consider approaching this:

1. Explicitly (constructor)

Build a wrapper service exposing the values from cookies and make your `UserClass` consume that. It's the simplest, least *magical* option that will be easy for anyone on your team to grasp.

2. `DynamicParameters` (constructor)

Use the [`DynamicDependencies`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md#supplying-dynamic-dependencies) feature to pass the cookie values through to the resolution pipeline. It ties you to Windsor and may not be super-obvious to every person on your team so you need to consider that.

3. `OnCreate` (init)

Use the [`OnCreate`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/35ebd6e5a77de289536b3862f366d6cbfad19ecc/docs/lifecycle.md#the-oncreate-method) feature to initialise the object post-construction. Pretty much the same idea as option 2, but used on an already-constructed object. This can work applying either explicit or implicit approach (that is 1. or 2. from above)

Like with everything, it's all a trade-off between what is technically possible and what makes sense for your code architecture and team.